# How to set parameters in a condition querying for multiple rows using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm using this code to querying a db in JdbcTemplate. My problem is that I don't know how to set the paramater for the condition (WHERE AGE > ?).
Thank you all for your answers

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE AGE > ?";

    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            sql,
            (rs, rowNum) ->
                    new Customer(
                            rs.getLong("id"),
                            rs.getString("name"),
                            rs.getInt("age"),
                            rs.getTimestamp("created_date").toLocalDateTime()
                    )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `queryForObject` to pass the placeholder values in array

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{age}, (rs, rowNum) ->
                new Customer(
                        rs.getLong("id"),
                        rs.getString("name"),
                        rs.getInt("age"),
                        rs.getTimestamp("created_date").toLocalDateTime()
                ));
```